# RSpec 3: How to stub methods and constants from code we have yet to build/add?

Tags: ruby, rspec

We are refactoring a Ruby application called DataSourceIntegrations from a gem we've built called DBQuery.  I am migrating some of the DBQuery code into DataSourceIntegrations.  The section I'm building depends on DBQuery, which will be added in a separate step.

Meanwhile, I need to write RSpec tests to verify that the DBQuery code is being called correctly, all without DBQuery.

What I have is:

Code—

Gem code—

```
module DBQuery
  class Query
    MAX = 1000

    def retrieve_users
      # Returns an array of user IDs
    end
  end
end
```

Application code—

```
  module Integration
    def initialize
      @query = DBQuery::Query.new
    end   
  end

  module Integration
    class StackOverflowIntegration
      include Integration

      def query
        users = []
        while (users < DBQuery::Query::MAX) do
          # Creates a users buffer
          users.push @query.retrieve_users(users_buffer)
        end
      end
    end   
  end
```

Tests—

```
describe Integration::StackOverflowIntegration do
  let(:db_query) { double('DBQuery::Query') }

  before do
    stub_const('DBQuery::Query::MAX', 1000)
    allow(db_query).to receive(:new).and_return(db_query)
    allow(db_query).to receive(:retrieve_users).and_return([1000, 1001, 1002])
  end

  it 'queries without error' do
    expect { StackOverflowIntegration.new.query }.to_not raise_error
  end
end
```

I can't figure out how to stub in a way that doesn't require DBQuery.  My error is:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `new' for #<Module:0x007fa7ce561968>
```

I don't know why DBQuery::Query is being represented as a module, or how to get it to recognize "new."

Comment: Can you think about a better name for `query`, perhaps `user_count` or something like that. Would be much easier to test if `@query` and the `query` method had different names and clear resposibilities.

Comment: Could you provide an excerpt from your `DBQuery::Query`? Just to be sure with what we're working here!

Comment: Your code does not work. `query` in `allow(query)` is not defined, in the `#query` method you are adding an array to an integer (you intended to get size?), and you `allow(query).to receive(:new)` but it should be `allow(DBQuery::Query).to receive(:new)`.

Comment: @cbliard this is not the actual code, but it's based on what I'm doing (the actual code is a bit long).  I meant db_query for query

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I understand, you want to make expectations on `DBQuery::Query` without defining it in your code. rspec-mocks can [stub an undefined constant](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/mutating-constants/stub-undefined-constant), like you did for `DBQuery::Query::MAX`. To stub `DBQuery::Query` completely, create a [class double](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/verifying-doubles/using-a-class-double) first and stub a const for it in your test:

```
db_query__query_class = class_double('DBQuery::Query')
stub_const('DBQuery::Query', db_query__query_class)
```

This way, `DBQuery::Query` in your code will return the `query_class` double. Then you can define some behavior with it:

```
query_instance = instance_double('DBQuery::Query')
allow(db_query__query_class).to receive(:new).and_return(query_instance)
allow(db_query).to receive(:retrieve_users).and_return([1000, 1001, 1002])
```

You still have to stub nested constants like `DBQuery::Query::MAX`

```
stub_const('DBQuery::Query::MAX', 1000)
```

About style, I prefer putting stubs and allows in `let`/`let!` statements like this:

```
describe Integration::StackOverflowIntegration do
  let!(:db_query__query_class) do
    class_double('DBQuery::Query').tap do |double|
      stub_const('DBQuery::Query', double)
      stub_const('DBQuery::Query::MAX', 1000)
      allow(double).to receive(:new).and_return(query_instance)
    end
  end
  let(:query_instance) do
    instance_double('DBQuery::Query').tap do |double|
      allow(double).to receive(:retrieve_users).and_return([1000, 10001, 1002])
    end
  end
end
```

Also I like to put returned values in their own `let` so I can change them easily. Here is a full working (and dummy) example:

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.around(:context, :protect_with_timeout) do |example|
    Timeout::timeout(2) {
      example.run
    }
  end
end

describe Integration::StackOverflowIntegration do
  let!(:db_query__query_class) do
    class_double('DBQuery::Query').tap do |double|
      stub_const('DBQuery::Query', double)
      stub_const('DBQuery::Query::MAX', max_queries)
      allow(double).to receive(:new).and_return(query_instance)
    end
  end
  let(:query_instance) do
    instance_double('DBQuery::Query').tap do |double|
      allow(double).to receive(:retrieve_users).and_return(retrieved_users)
    end
  end
  let(:max_queries) { 1000 }
  let(:retrieved_users) { [1000, 1001, 1002] }

  describe '#query' do
    subject(:stack_overflow_query) { Integration::StackOverflowIntegration.new.query }

    it 'queries without error in nominal case' do
      expect { stack_overflow_query }.to_not raise_error
    end

    context 'with 0 users returned' do
      let(:retrieved_users) { [] }

      it 'does not loop forever', :protect_with_timeout do
        pending('not implemented yet...')
        stack_overflow_query # will timeout
      end
    end

    context 'with 10 users returned' do
      let(:retrieved_users) { [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] }

      it 'calls #retrieve_users 100 times' do
        stack_overflow_query
        expect(query_instance).to have_received(:retrieve_users).exactly(100).times
      end
    end

    context 'with DBQuery::Query::MAX set to 0' do
      let(:max_queries) { 0 }

      it 'does not call #retrieve_users at all' do
        stack_overflow_query
        expect(query_instance).not_to have_received(:retrieve_users)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured there would be a simple Ruby solution hiding in there.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer was, at the beginning of the RSpec:

```
let(:db_query_class) { class_double('DBQuery::Query') }
let(:db_query) { instance_double('DBQuery::Query') }

before do
  stub_const('DBQuery::Query', db_query_class)
  allow(db_query_class).to receive(:new).and_return(db_query)
  allow(db_query).to receive(:retrieve_users).and_return([1000, 1001, 1002])
  stub_const('DBQuery::Query::MAX', 1000)
end
```